# Issue related to import excel file in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, excel, ruby-on-rails-4, import

I am following Ryan Bates railscast website as tutorial for importing an excel file into my rails application. And finally I have done it. Now I want to perform a bit more complex operations with this excel data. I am able to import the whole content of the excel file into the database table. But now I want to get each row of the excel file before inserting into database. I need to perform operations on each row of excel file. I don't know how to achieve this.

My model name is Employee and so my table name is employees.
Now my model is:-

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base

def self.import(file)
    spreadsheet= Employee.open_spreadsheet(file)
    header=spreadsheet.row(1)
    (2..spreadsheet.last_row).each do |i|
        row=Hash[[header,spreadsheet.row(i)].transpose]
        em=find_by_id(row["id"])||new
        em.attributes=row.to_hash.slice('firstname')
        em.save
    end
end

def self.open_spreadsheet(file)
    case File.extname(file.original_filename)
    #when ".csv" then Roo::Csv.new (file.path nil, :ignore)
    when ".xlsx" then Roo::Excelx.new (file.path)
    #when ".xlsx" then Excelx.new (file.path, nil, :ignore)
    else raise "Unknown file type: #{file.original_filename}"
    end
end

end
```

Another problem is that I want to pass the content of the row to controller, but I know that in MVC architecture I should not pass model data to controller. Then tell me is there any way out?

Comment: What kind of operations are you looking to perform on each row of the spreadsheet?

Comment: Actually I want to get the data from each row of my excel file (my excel contains only one column) an then to convert the fetched string to another string without any special character. I want to perform this jobs in controller.

Answer (score 0):

Don't idolize MVC, all the more so importing data is not model-related thing. If you care about clean MVC - move your code to the rake task.

Is it a background task? If so, you don't need even controller.
Otherwise if you have some user actions on the fetched strings, put your code to the controller (e.g, user uploads an excel file, inputs data for the convertation etc).

You (or users) can modify the data in iterator. `row` is a hash with the header as the key and the value as the ceil content. E.g., if you want to remove the special characters:

```
def self.import(file)
  spreadsheet = Employee.open_spreadsheet(file)
  header = spreadsheet.row(1)
  (2..spreadsheet.last_row).each do |data|
    spreadsheet.row(data).map! do |ceil| 
      ceil.class == String ? ceil.gsub!(/[!@%&"]/,'') : ceil }
    end

    row = Hash[[header,spreadsheet.row(data)].transpose]

    em = find_by_id(row["id"]) || new
    em.attributes = row.to_hash.slice('firstname')
    em.save
  end
end
```

Comment: can I put this import method (the above code) in my controller?

Comment: I updated the answer. Yes, you can put that code to your controller (I assume you are using POST).

Comment: Yeah .But in my case it is obtained by just writing 'spreadsheet.row(i)' in the loop with context of i